# Non-trivial solution of x$^2$ y''+ 4x$^3$ y' + (4x$^4$ + 3x$^2$ + 2)y = 0 oscillate on the positive x-axis?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Converted to Normal Form u'' + (1+2$/x^2$)u = 0, which has infinitely many zeroes in positive x-axis what next how to prove the nontrivial solutions are oscillatory

Comment: That should be sufficient, infinitely many discrete zeros means that the solution oscillates. You could mention that there is a minimum distance between roots for $x>1$. For anything more you would need a more detailed definition of what "oscillates" means. // If you could, please add what $u$ is relative to $y$ and what the Sturm-Picone comparison theorem tells in more detail. Your homework solution should in any case contain these points.

Answer (score 0):

To arrive to the normal form, I suppose that you properly used $y(x)=u(x) \,e^{-x^2}$
$$u''(x)+\left(1+\frac{2}{x^2}\right) u(x)=0$$is a Bessel differential equation

If you look [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html), using Bowman's transformed version of Bessel differential equations, your case corresponds to
$\alpha=\frac 12$, $\gamma=1$, $\beta=\sqrt 2$ and $n^2=-\frac 74$. So

$$u(x)=\sqrt{x} \left(c_1\, J_{\frac{i \sqrt{7}}{2}}(x)+c_2 \,Y_{\frac{i \sqrt{7}}{2}}(x)\right)$$
Remember that all Bessel functions have an infinite number of zero's. Moreover, for this, the order is a pure imaginary number. So, for any boundary conditions, both $\Re(u(x))$ and $\Im(u(x))$ will show an infinite number of zeros and, for sure, an oscillating behavior.